# Saving file as a double byte unicode in Java?

Tags: java, unicode, unicode-string, mql5

Okay, I'm running Java6 (App requirement) and I need to save a file in unicode format (no big endian or low endian), only double byte unicode.
I did this:

```
 BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(
     new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(f), "UTF-8"));
 bw.write(dec+",");
 bw.flush();
 bw.close();
```

where `dec` is a string.

I also tried UTF-16 and Unicode. They all write a unicode big endian file. The problem is, this file is read by a scripting language that only accept double byte unicode and ANSI too but I want to use unicode. 
http://www.mql5.com/en/docs/constants/io_constants/fileflags

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  What order do you want the bytes in? Are you talking about a BOM?

Comment: Apparently you don't understand that UTF-16 is **either** big-endian **or** little-endian since there are exactly two ways to sequentially arrange the two bytes you are talking about.

Answer (score 4):

Inferring from your question that it's the endianness which is the problem, you want `UTF-16LE` as the encoding name. From the `Charset` docs listing the mandatory encodings which are always supported:

> UTF-16LE - Sixteen-bit UCS Transformation Format, little-endian byte order